# ionic 3 http get request returns undefined

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, ionic3, http-get, ionic-native

I'm using the ionic native geolocation plugin and google maps geocoding api to transform lat/long to an address, specifically to get a user's `city`. I then want to pass this string to another api that gets news based on the `city` string. The function works well up to the point where I try to get the city and nothing else. When I try to get a user's city from the JSON it returns as `undefined` and my news api searches for the literal name "undefined" rather than the user's city.

```
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp.coords.latitude)
                console.log(resp.coords.longitude)
                this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+ resp.coords.latitude + ',' + resp.coords.longitude + '&result_type=locality&key=[MY API KEY]')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
                  this.objects = data;
    //the data is logged here
                  console.log(data)
    //the data is undefined here
                  console.log(data.results.formatted_address)
          let city = data.results.formatted_address
```

I have no clue why for one the data is logged and for the other it returns undefined. I'm also attaching the response I get in the browser. Any hints would be VERY appreciated. [JSON in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFNax.png)

Comment: try `data.results[0].formatted_address`

Comment: Agree with Duannx, you are getting Array in response, so you should traverse it accordingly.